# Sets $A$ such that $A$-maximal sets are $\Delta^0_2$

Tags: computability-theory

Recall that $M\subseteq\omega$ is **maximal** if it is c.e., and can be only trivially extended by other c.e. sets, i.e. if $M\subseteq N$ and $N$ is c.e., then either $\overline{N}$ or $N\setminus M$ is finite. Similarly say a set $M$ is **$A$-maximal** if it is $A$-c.e. and only trivially extended by other $A$-c.e. sets.

I am interested in sets $A$ such that all $A$-maximal sets are $\Delta^0_2$. If $A$ has this property, then relativizing Yates' construction of a complete maximal set gives an $A$-maximal $M$ with $M\oplus A\equiv_T A'$, so that $A$ is $\mathrm{GL}_1$.

Thus among $A\in\Delta^0_2$, the sets with this property are exactly the low ones - one direction is above, and for the reverse, if $A$ is low then all $A$-c.e. sets are $\Delta^0_2$.

My question is - is this property enjoyed by any non-$\Delta^0_2$ set?

<s>By Martin's high domination theorem, this condition is equivalent to asking for a set $A$ such that all $A$-high, $A$-c.e. sets are $\Delta^0_2$ and high, i.e. if $B\in\Sigma^0_1(A)$ and $(B\oplus A)'\equiv_T A''$, then $B\in\Delta^0_2$ and $B'\equiv_T \emptyset''$.</s> **Edit**: My understanding of the relativization of Martin's result was incorrect (thanks to Emma Harper on Twitter for spotting this!). The correct statement is that if a set $B$ is $A$-c.e. and $A$-high, there is an $A$-maximal $M$ with $M\oplus A\equiv_T B\oplus A$, so what I struck through is not obviously equivalent to the property I am concerned with. Indeed, it does not hold outside of the $\Delta^0_2$ degrees, as Noah correctly points out below.

My suspicion is that this requirement is too strong, that if $A\not\in\Delta^0_2$ *some* $A$-maximal real will always fail to be in $\Delta^0_2$. But I do not have a proof, nor can I rule out that some 'weak' set (like a hyperimmune-free or a bi-immune-free) might somehow have this property.

Comment: If $B\ge_TA$ is $A$-c.e. and $A$-high (so just relativize the usual high c.e. construction to $A$) we must have $B\not\in\Delta^0_2$ since $\Delta^0_2$ is closed downwards. Or am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: When we say it's $A$-high, doesn't that only give that $(B\oplus A)'$ is above $A$, not necessarily $B$ itself?

Comment: Sure, but I'm saying we can always construct an $A$-high $A$-c.e. which is itself above $A$.

Comment: Ah, okay, Bjorn and I somehow missed that. That settles it!

Comment: @NoahSchweber but how do you make it above $A$?

Comment: @BjørnKjos-Hanssen If $B$ is $A$-c.e. and $A$-high, then so is $B\oplus A$, right? (Or: just start the usual construction of an $A$-high $A$-c.e. set but with $A$ itself "pre-coded" into one of the rows of the set you're building. This should amount to the same thing I think.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber if $A$ is precoded then that conflicts with maximality does it not?

Comment: @BjørnKjos-Hanssen I'm not thinking about maximality at all, I'm addressing the OP's (now-deleted?) variant question: "By Martin's high domination theorem, this is equivalent to asking for a set $A$ such that all $A$-high, $A$-c.e. sets are $\Delta^0_2$ and high." I'm merely claiming that there is no non-$\Delta^0_2$ set $A$ such that all $A$-high $A$-c.e. sets are $\Delta^0_2$.

Comment: Mm, I did delete that since the question was settled, so I suppose it comes down to whether I understand correctly how to relativize Martin's result that every high c.e. degree contains a maximal set - it should be that every A-high, A-c.e. degree contains an A-maximal set, but I haven't worked through the details

Comment: @NoahSchweber ah okay. The interesting question is about maximality anyway

Comment: I now suspect the relativization of Martin is not as nice as I hoped, which nixes my comments about an equivalent characterization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out (as I suspected!) all such sets are $\Delta^0_2$, so that this property exactly characterizes lowness.

Fix an $A$-maximal $M$. For any $B\leq_T A$, one can build $C = \overline{M}\oplus_B\emptyset = \{n \mid p_B(n)\in\overline{M}\}$. Then any $W_e^A$ you might wish to intersect with $C$ can be transformed into a $W_{f(e)}^A$ (to be intersected with $\overline{M}$) by putting $n$ into $W_{f(e)}^A$ whenever $p_B(n)$ enters $W_e^A$.

Now the $A$-cohesiveness of $\overline{M}$ carries over nicely to $C$, since $|W_e^A\cap C| = |W_{f(e)}^A\cap\overline{M}|$ (and similarly for $\overline{W_e^A}$). So since $\overline{C}$ is $A$-c.e. and $A$-cohesive, it is $A$-maximal and thus $\Delta^0_2$.

Finally any $B\leq_T A$ has a $\Delta^0_2$ subset, which happens only when $A\in\Delta^0_2$.